How to set Quasar Language with SSR Mode from route param?
How to use Quasar Language Packs with this kind of route and SSR mode?
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/:locale?',
    beforeEnter: localeNavGuard,
    children: [ ... ]
  }
]


Make a boot file for Quasar lang pack:
import { Lang } from 'quasar'

// relative path to your node_modules/quasar/..
// change to YOUR path
const langList = import.meta.glob('../../node_modules/quasar/lang/*.js')
// or just a select few (example below with only DE and FR):
// import.meta.glob('../../node_modules/quasar/lang/(de|fr).js')

// ! NOTICE ssrContext param:
export default async ({ ssrContext, router }) => {
  router.beforeEach((to, _from, next) =>
  const langIso = to.params.locale
  try {
    const lang = await langList[ `../../node_modules/quasar/lang/${ langIso }.js` ]()
    Lang.set(lang.default, ssrContext)
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    // Requested Quasar Language Pack does not exist,
    // let's not break the app, so catching error
  }

    return next()
  })
}

Routes:
import { locales } from 'src/i18n/config'

const routes = [
  {
    path: `/:locale(${locales.join('|')})?`,
    children: [ ... ]
  }
]

